# В Буковеле, на Буковеле, в Буковели или на Буковели?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Многим известен горнолыжный курорт, или же туристический комплекс, Буковель. Но в употреблении этого слова большая, как мне кажется, путаница. Буковель - это не населенный пункт, а всего лишь название курорта в Ивано-Франковской области (Украина). Поэтому вроде бы нет основания писать "в БуковелЕ" - по аналогии "в Гомеле".
Кроме того, название курорта происходит от названия горы Буковель. Если подразумевать, что Буковель - гора, то логично писать "на БуковелИ". Но в действительности мы все же подразумеваем курорт, а не гору. Поэтому этот вариант отпадает.
Вариант "в БуковелИ" также отпадает, ведь не существует населенного пункта "Буковель" женского рода.
В Википедии пишут и "в Буковеле", и "на Буковели". Но, по-моему, это тот случай, когда надо унифицировать это "разнообразие".
Большинство мнений коллег-лингвистов сошлись на версии "в БуковелЕ". Но я не могу с этим согласиться. Какое ваше мнение?

Да, и еще про кавычки: нужно ли в каких-либо случаях писать "Буковель"?

Answer (score 2):

Мое мнение таково: слово Буковель женского рода, о чем нам говорит и мягкий знак в конце слова (3 склонение - имена существительные женского рода с нулевым окончанием в именительном падеже единственного числа, с основой на мягкий знак, исключения, относящиеся к этому склонению не женского рода: слово путь и 10 слов среднего рода), и тот факт, что это название горы, значит, писать нужно "на Буковели" и в том случае, когда речь идет о горе, и в том случае, когда речь идет о курорте, по правилам склонения существительных. Пишем "на", т.к. с названием горы употребляется именно этот предлог и с названием курорта также, мы не говорим "в курорте", мы не говорим, например, "в Куяльнике".

Comment: Тем не менее Интернет пестрит вариантом "в Куяльнике". На мой взгляд, это приемлемо, ведь Куяльник таки является населенным пунктом (село в Котовском районе Одесской обл.), в котором и расположен курорт. Пока не знаю, можно ли выбрать здесь один-единственный вариант. Скорее вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что тут можно писать по-разному, в зависимости от того, в каком контексте употребляется это название. Если речь о курорте, то "в Буколеле", если о горе - то "на".
Что же до кавычек, то они уместны только в том случае, если речь о названии, например, санатория или базы отдыха. Если же речь идет о географическом объекте, то кавычки не нужны.

Comment: Я больше склоняюсь к варианту "на Буковеле" (на курорте) и на Буковели (на горе).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще вопрос решается просто. Надо посмотреть в каком-нибудь подходящем справочнике неографических названий. У меня под рукой нету, поэтому просто теоретизирую.

Хочется, конечно, считать Буковель мужского рода по аналогии с Куршевель, но слишком уж несерьёзна аналогия...

Кстати случаев, когда бы топоним менял грамматический род в зависимости он конкретного объекта (город и река, скажем), я не припомню.